# Using modernizr.js / yepnope.js to load Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, modernizr, yepnope

Does anybody have any working code that allows one to use modernizr.load or yepnope to load the Google Maps API?

I am able to load JQuery & GMap3 using modernizr, however Google Maps API doesn't work unless I make a traditional script tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Please help me load Google Maps API with modernizr!</title>
    <style>
        #map { width: 500px; height: 300px; }
    </style>
    <script src="/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Please help me load Google Maps API with modernizr!</h1>

    <div id="map">
        Placeholder
    </div>

    <script>
        function pageInit() {
            $("#map").gmap3({
                map:{
                    options: {
                        center: [18.01714, -76.750113],
                        zoom: 15,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>


    <!-- I WANT TO REMOVE THE SCRIPT TAG BELOW AND REPLACE WITH MODERNIZR LOAD! -->
    <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en"></script>
    <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->


    <script>
        Modernizr.load([{load: [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js',
            '/js/gmap.jquery-5.1.1.min.js',
        ],complete: function () {loaded();}},]);

        function loaded() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                pageInit();
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Well logic tells me I should do the following change after removing the script tag:-

```
Modernizr.load([{load: [
    '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js',
    '//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en',
    '/js/gmap.jquery-5.1.1.min.js',
```

But if I do this change the map doesn't load and I now get this error in the Javascript console:-

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

Comment: Hmmmmm.....

"COMMON GOTCHAS

You cannot use document.write() (which means no google maps or ads) in the scripts that you load with yepnope. This is true for every asynchronous script loader. We suggest that you avoid document.writes all the time though."

http://yepnopejs.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is best I can come up with:-

```
    <script>
        Modernizr.load([{load: [
            'preload!//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=loaded',
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js',
            '/js/gmap.jquery-5.1.1.min.js',
        ], complete: function () {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=loaded';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }}]);

        function loaded() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                pageInit();
            });
        }
    </script>
```

It seems quicker with the preload! However I think it's grabbing the file twice judging by what Firebug tells me.

Answer (score 0):

Altering the Access-Control-Allow-Origin head to allow Google's API URL to your page header will get rid of the security issue.

For example Apache .htaccess:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js*"
```

or via php:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js*', true);
```

Although I am not 100% on the security ramifications of doing such a thing. Google API is a big library. See http://code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/CrossOriginRequestSecurity and the section `Processing rogue COR`

Side note, I'm not a fan of this also because it adds the additional header to every request.